# Removing Duplicate in SSIS wheere not all columns is same in SSIS

Tags: ssis, duplicates

I have situation where in I want to find duplicate value where not all column data is same in SSIS.

I am aware of doing it using sort and aggregate method but i guess that can be done in case where all column data is same

```
ID             | Start Date | End Time | Queue Time | Talk Time|
===============|============|==========|============|==========|
33000017670    |9/4/2017    |9/4/2017  |0:00:10     |0:03:30   |
33000017672    |9/4/2017    |9/4/2017  |0:00:10     |0:03:30   |
33000017672    |9/4/2017    |9/4/2017  |0:00:12     |0:00:00   |
33000017673    |9/4/2017    |9/4/2017  |0:00:12     |0:05:00   |
33000017674    |9/4/2017    |9/4/2017  |0:00:12     |0:12:00   |
```

So as you can see here id **33000017672** is coming twice and it is a primary key in the table that I am loading this data. The source of it is Excel. I am aware of removing this record before loading but I want to remove that process.

Now here not all the record column data is same. I want to find such record remove id which do have **Talk Time** is 0

Can someone help me how I can do it in SSIS

Comment: What if there are duplicates where both of the rows have Talk Time greater than 0?   Do you want to remove all rows with 0 Talk Time even if they are not a duplicate?

Comment: Only duplicates which have talk time 0. And there wont be any duplicates with Talk Time greater than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the really simple method and i think the best practice too is that you stage all your data to a table. And on that table you make your logic. This way you will always have the truth from the source, and then you can add as much logic as you want afterwards. There is no point in making your SSIS too complex.

I did this as an FLAT FILE, because i hate EXCEL Source, but its pretty much the same.

[image]

And then i want to apply my logic - You could use this in a new Dataflow Task 
with an OLDB Source after your staged Dataflow Task.

```
Select * from (
SELECT [ID]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndTime]
  ,[Qtime]
  ,[Ttime]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by ID order by TTime desc) as RN
FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[TTimeTable]
) x

where x.RN = 1
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Isnt there any other way to do it.

Comment: I cant see why you would put such logic into ssis. This is the best way